# R identifying type of frequency distribution

Tags: r, frequency-distribution

I am interested in frequency distributions that are not normally distributed.
If I have a  frequency distributions table which is not normally distributed.
Is there a function or package that will identify the type of distribution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fitdistr` function (library MASS i think) and check for yourself if you find a 'fitting' distribution. However i suggest that you plot the function first and see how it looks like. This approach is generally not recommended as you always can use different parameters to fit a distribution and thus confuse one distribution with another. If you have found a suited distribution you should test it against data.

Edit: For instance a normal distribution may look like a poisson distribution. Fitting is in my oppinion only useful if you have enough random variables. Otherwise just draw variables from your data if you need to

Answer (score 2):

You can always try to test whether a distribution is adequate for your data with [QQ plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot). If you have data that is dynamic, I would suggest that you use ECDF (Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function) which will give you more precise distributions as your data grows. You can use ECDF in R with the [ecdf() function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ecdf.html).